# Not able to remove a column from hive table

Tags: hive

I am not able to remove a column  using ALTER from  an existing hive external table

Hive version is hive 1.1 inside CDH 5.5

```
 hive> create external table alter_test(id int,name string)
> row format delimited
> fields terminated by ','
> location '/user/cloudera/conf_files';
OK
 Time taken: 0.132 seconds
 hive> select * from alter_test;
 OK
 100     surender
 101     raja
 Time taken: 0.141 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
  hive> alter table alter_test ADD COLUMNS (deviceid string,mode string,channels int,action_name string,data_countt int);
 OK
 Time taken: 0.2 seconds
 hive> show create table alter_test;
 OK
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `alter_test`(
`id` int,
`name` string,
`deviceid` string,
`mode` string,
`channels` int,
`action_name` string,
`data_countt` int)
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
 OUTPUTFORMAT
 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
 'hdfs://nameservice1/user/cloudera/conf_files'
 TBLPROPERTIES (
 'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='false',
   'last_modified_by'='build',
   'last_modified_time'='1500048081',
   'numFiles'='0',
   'numRows'='-1',
   'rawDataSize'='-1',
   'totalSize'='0',
   'transient_lastDdlTime'='1500048081')
   Time taken: 0.049 seconds, Fetched: 25 row(s)
  hive> select * from alter_test;
  OK
 100     surender        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
 101     raja    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
   Time taken: 0.123 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
      hive> alter table alter_test drop deviceid;
       MismatchedTokenException(26!=187)
    at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.recoverFromMismatchedToken(BaseRecognizer.java:617)
    at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.match(BaseRecognizer.java:115)
    at    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.dropPartitionSpec(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:10571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.dropPartitionSpec (HiveParser.java:44608)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.alterStatementSuffixDropPartitions(HiveParser.java:11198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.alterTableStatementSuffix(HiveParser.java:7748)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.alterStatement(HiveParser.java:6960)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:2409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1062)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1158)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1037)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:615)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
       FAILED: ParseException line 1:28 mismatched input 'deviceid' expecting PARTITION near 'drop' in drop partition statement
       hive> alter table alter_test drop column  deviceid;
       MismatchedTokenException(57!=187)
    at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.recoverFromMismatchedToken(BaseRecognizer.java:617)
    at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.match(BaseRecognizer.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.dropPartitionSpec(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:10571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.dropPartitionSpec(HiveParser.java:44608)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.alterStatementSuffixDropPartitions(HiveParser.java:11198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.alterTableStatementSuffix(HiveParser.java:7748)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.alterStatement(HiveParser.java:6960)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:2409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1062)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1158)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1037)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:615)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
   FAILED: ParseException line 1:28 mismatched input 'column' expecting PARTITION near 'drop' in drop partition statement
```

Is there any workaround to come out of this issue?

Comment: Add the table definition to your post (`show create table omega_temp`)

Comment: @Dudu : I pasted the error and show create table command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no command in Hive for dropping a column.

A column could be dropped implicitly by defining a new set of columns -

```
alter table alter_test 
replace columns
(id int,name string,mode string,channels int,action_name string,data_countt int)
;
```

However, in your case it raises an exception -

> Unable to alter table.
>   The following columns have types incompatible
>   with the existing columns in their respective positions :
>   channels,data_countt,
>   Query: alter table alter_test replace columns
>   (id int,name string,mode string,channels int,action_name
>   string,data_countt int).

We can work around it by doing it in 2 phases -

1.

```
alter table alter_test 
replace columns
(id int,name string)
;
```

2.

```
alter table alter_test 
add columns
(mode string,channels int,action_name string,data_countt int)
;
```

P.s.
Just to make it clear -
All the change are done in the metadata level only.
The data is not being changed.

P.s. 2
And off course you can drop the external table and recreate it...

Answer (score 0):

it's better to create a new table a,then insert into table a from old table,after this drop the old table ,finally rename a to the old table name.